# CSS - I can't change link color of existing theme

Tags: css, background, hyperlink

I'm attempting to override the link color in a certain area of an existing theme. The links are blue on a blue background by default. I'm not sure how this theme was approved to be offered to customers, but I'm going to attempt a simple fix by making links in this area white.

Here is the markup of the area of the page with the problem:

```
<div id="product_details_customtab2_tab">
    <a href="http://www.example.com/">example</a>
</div>
```

Here was one of my unsuccessful fix attempts. I tried dozens of similar things. None worked.

```
#product_details_customtab2_tab {link{color: white !important}}
```

However, the links in the area I wished to fix did not change. (There is an admin area where I can add custom CSS, so I inserted this there. I can make other styles in other areas of the theme change, so the basic functionality works, but in this specific case I don't have the details right.)

What is wrong with my CSS? Have I given enough info in this question? Thanks

**UPDATE:** Here's the solution that worked:

```
#product_details_customtab2_tab a:link{color: white}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Please reduce your code sample to the applicable parts and format appropriately. You've got way too much in there and it's not readable as-is.

Comment: I edited this code. We need wait for review.

Comment: You and me both @WooCaSh haha

Comment: I edited further. Keeping the code sample relevant to the question makes it a lot easier to answer. Having multiple links and multiple nested divs isn't applicable to the problem, so a single link inside a single div defines the problem fully.

Comment: Are you using some sort of dynamic CSS language?

Comment: The reason I included all that markup is because I wasn't sure about precedence. In fact, I thought the nested div's were the reason I couldn't get my CSS to work, so I felt it was necessary to include the full nested markup structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is wrong... there is no standalone CSS "link" selector, only the ":link" selector:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_link.asp

Also, to use CSS inheritance, you only need to separate each part of the inheritance chain with a space, not wrap it in {}. i.e., if you want to change all links inside a div with id "foo" you would do this:

```
#foo a { ... } /* CORRECT */
```

and NOT This:

```
#foo { a { ... } } /* WRONG */
```

I assume that you either wanted to do this:

```
#product_details_customtab2_tab a{color: white !important}
```

or this:

```
#product_details_customtab2_tab a:link{color: white !important}
```

Comment: @MountainX: If possible, skip the `!important`. It's a bad habit if not necessary.

Comment: I dropped !important now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is not valid. To make a selector inside another selector, you just need a space, like:

```
#product_details_customtab2_tab a { color: white; }
```

This will select all `a` elements inside that div.